# Make Highchart R the full width and height of the box in Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

Hello I have a box that renders a highchart object. The issue I am having is there is a lot of white space around the chart in the box. Is there a way to make the graph take up the whole space so no white is showing?

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

    df = data.frame(x = 1:100, y =rnorm(100))

 shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
   old_school = FALSE,
   sidebar_min = TRUE,
   sidebar_collapsed = FALSE,
   controlbar_collapsed = FALSE,
   controlbar_overlay = TRUE,
   title = "Basic Dashboard",
   navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
   sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
   controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
   footer = bs4DashFooter(),
   body = bs4DashBody(
    fluidRow(
       bs4Card(
          width = 4,
          title = "Net Investing Cash Flow",
          highchartOutput("graph")
        )
    ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$graph = renderHighchart({
      highchart() %>% hc_xAxis(categories = df$x) %>% hc_add_series(name = "Earnings Yield",  data = df$y)%>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_darkunica())
    })
}
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, you will have to supply us with more code. I can't reproduce your problem and probably has to do with that you are using some library (shiydashboard??) that includes some css. And that is where the problem is comming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to override the bootstrap css for the boxes. To find which css class we need to modify we print out the result from the box function in our console.

```
box(
  width = 4,
  title = "Net Investing Cash Flow",
  highchartOutput("graph")
)


<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">Net Investing Cash Flow</h3>
      <div class="card-tools">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
          <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="graph" style="width:100%; height:400px; " class="highchart html-widget html-widget-output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We can now see that the highchart is placed in a `div` with the class `card-body` That means we should add the following code somewhere in our `dashboardBody` in the UI code.

```
tags$head(
      tags$style(
        ".card-body {
           padding: 0px;
        }"
      )
    ),
```

this will override the css from shinydashboard. The `tags$head` will make sure that the css is placed in the head tag your document which is the place where we want all the css code. placing the code in the dashboardBody will make sure the staly comes at the end of the head tag - we want that since that makes it override any css added earlier

Comment: Hi Bertil, I am actually using the package bs4dash which is a bootstrap 4 version of shiny. Instead of box they have bs4Card. I tried switching .box with .bs4Card and still I am unable to get it working. I am editing my post with more code right now

Comment: Maybe try with ".card-body" class instead of ".box-body". Let me know if it worked

Comment: I updated the answer to work with the package bs4Dash

Comment: @BertilBaron where do i place the code in my application? I actually tried doing it in the body() section but for some reason it did not work